# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen vermelden und melden?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

z.B.

> Von der Autoindostrie ist Positives zu **vermelden**: BMW legte um 3
>   Prozent zu und auch VW **meldet** ein leichtes Plus. Dagegen ein
>   schlechter Tag für die Banken: Deutsche Bank minus 5 Prozent und die
>   DZ Bank minus 7. Nichts Neues von da Bahn; die DB **meldete** plus minus
>   0.

Comment: Das ist in den Medien ein üblicher Jargon -- nicht gerade gutes Deutsch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Vermelden* fällt für mich in die selbe Kategorie wie *verkünden*, *verzeichnen*, *verlauten* oder *veröffentlichen*. Die Botschaft hat dabei keinen Adressaten, sondern wird einfach publik gemacht. Der Unterschied liegt also darin, dass du *jemandem etwas melden* kannst, aber nicht *jemandem etwas vermelden*.

Comment: klingt nach intransitiv - transitiv.
In der Presse wird fast nur noch "vermeldet". Ich wünschte, Karl Kraus könnte dieser Unsitte, die aus deren sprachlichem Unvermögen stammt, gebührend zu Leibe rücken.